# Set state for a hook functional component inside another functional component

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a website where the user can search for a query and the results are shown.

I created two components: `Searchbar` and `ResultList`, both are functional components with hooks.

**Searchbar**

The user writes a query, which is sent via axios POST request to the backend when the user preses enter.
The backend search the relative query and sends the results back via axios GET request.
**This is working**.

**ResultList**

The ResultList state is initialised with an array called `results`.

**What I would like:**
I want to set the `results` array equal to the what it is returned from the GET request in the Searchbar.

**Searchbar code**

```
function Searchbar() {

    const [query, setQuery] = useState("");



    function handlePostQuery(query){

        var myParams = {
            data: query
        }

        if (query != "") {
            axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/query', myParams)
            .then(function(response){
                    var instructions_div = document.getElementsByClassName("instructions")[0];
                    instructions_div.style.display = "none";

                    console.log("Yes, it sends the query in JSON format to Flask");
           //Perform action based on response
            })
            .catch(function(error){
                console.log(error, "Error on AXIOS post");
           //Perform action based on error
        });

      axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/query')
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log("AXIOS GET")
          console.log(response);

        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
      } else {
            alert("The search query cannot be empty")
        }
    }

    return(
    <div>
        <SearchBar
            onChange={(event) => setQuery(event)}
            onRequestSearch={() => handlePostQuery(query)}


            style={{
                marginTop: 200,
                marginLeft: 'auto',
                marginRight: 'auto',
                maxWidth: 800,
            }}
        />
      <ResultList /> # I think I should set the new state of Resultlist here but not sure how
</div>
    )
}


export default Searchbar;
```

**ResultList code**

```
function ResultList() {

    const [results, setResults] = useState(["myemptyinitiallist"]);


  if (results[0] !== "myemptyinitiallist") {
        return (
            <div className="resultlist">
            This should appear only if results is different from "myemptyinitiallist"

            </div>
        )
    } else {
        return(
      <h1>This should appear when results is empty</h1>
        )
    }
}


export default ResultList;
```

**IDEALLY** I would like NOT to use class components.

Comment: `ResultList` should accept props. It's not responsible for its own state. The state should belong in `Searchbar`

Comment: Also why are you directly interfering with the DOM from handlePostQuery?

Comment: So you are suggesting to add `const [results, setResuts]=useState(["myemptyinitiallist"]);` in my `Searchbar`. And to do something `setResults(response)` in my axios GET?

Comment: I tried `axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/query')
        .then(response => setResults(["trytry"]))
        .then(console.log(results))` but `results` has not changed value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the response is handled from its parent, it should be a prop in the `ResultList`

Update the code as

```
function Searchbar() {
    const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
    const [results, setResults] = useState("");
...
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/query')
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log("AXIOS GET")
          console.log(response);
          setResults(response.data); //set the value
        })
...
   <ResultList results={results}/>
```

in ResultList

```
function ResultList({results}) { // destructuring props to get results
  //  const [results, setResults] = useState(["myemptyinitiallist"]); passed as props from parent

  if (results && results[0] !== "myemptyinitiallist") { // make sure the results is set before accessing value at [0]
        return (
            <div className="resultlist">
            This should appear only if results is different from "myemptyinitiallist"
            </div>
        )
    } else {
        return(
      <h1>This should appear when results is empty</h1>
        )
    }
}


export default ResultList;
```

Comment: Thanks, now I understand better. But if i do as you said, the `GET` is executed before the `POST`. I need the other way around otherwise then the user clicks `enter` on the keyboard it returns the wrong errors.

Comment: if you want the POST to wait for GET to finish you should move it to inside the `.then()` of the first GET request or use async/await

Comment: Thanks. I tried it does not seems to work as intended: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58365213/the-promise-is-not-executed-first