# The Promise is not executed first

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and I am creating a website where the user can search for a query and the results are shown.

I have one component called: `Searchbar` which contains two functions:

1) `postQuery()` The user writes a query, which is sent via axios POST request to the backend when the user presses enter.

2) `getQueryResult()` The backend searches the relative query and sends the results back via axios GET request.

Therefore the order is: postQuery()-->getQueryResult() so I think that postQuery() creates a promise that, if resolved, allows getQueryResult() to run.
**However** when the user clicks enter the first time, the `results` variable does not get updated. Only when he clicks enter the second, third etc. time the setResult updates the `results`. Therefore I think that my Promise of `postQuery()` is not executed first.

This is what I get in console:

[image: Console]

The first time, when enter is pressed for the first time, the `results` does not get updated. But the second time yes.

**Searchbar code**

```
function Searchbar() {

  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [results, setResults] = useState(["myemptyinitiallist"]);

  function postQuery(query) {
    console.log(query)
    var myParams = {
      data: query
    }

    return axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/query', myParams)
      .then(function(response){
        // console.log("Yes, it sends the query in JSON format to Flask");
      })
      .catch(function(error){
        console.log(error, "Error on AXIOS post");
        throw error; // don't fulfill returned promise
      });
  } // End of function:  postQuery()

  function getQueryResult() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/query')
      .then(function (response) {
        setResults(response.data); //set the value
        // console.log(response.data["my_results"])
        // console.log(results)
      })
  } // End of function: getQueryResult()

    function handleEnter(query){
        if (query != "") {
      postQuery(query).then(() => getQueryResult());
      console.log(results)
    } else {
        alert("The search query cannot be empty")
      }
  } // End of function: handleEnter()



    return(
    <div>
        <SearchBar
            onChange={(event) => setQuery(event)}
            onRequestSearch={() => handleEnter(query)}
            style={{
                marginTop: 200,
                marginLeft: 'auto',
                marginRight: 'auto',
                maxWidth: 800,
            }}
        />
     <ResultList/>
</div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Your `getQueryResult` doesn't return a promise. Do that instead of calling `setResults`. Then wait for the promise result in your `handleEnter` function - do not immediately `console.log(results)` before they will become available in the future.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand correctly. Why do I need a Promise for `getQuesryResult`? I thought the following: `postQuery` executes-->It returns a Promise-->If the promise is valid-->`setQueryResult` executes--> It sets the new value of `results` via `setResults`

Comment: Yes, that's what it currently does. But your `handleEnter` function tries to log the `results` before they are set, and returning a promise from `getQueryResult` is the proper solution to allow `handleEnter` to wait for them - just like you made the `getQueryResult()` call wait for the `postQuery()` promise.

Comment: I tried also:       `postQuery(query).then(() => getQueryResult().then((fetched_results)=>setResults(fetched_results)));` but same problem

Comment: That should work. But you will need to omit the `console.log(results)`, and instead put a `console.log(fetched_results)` in that callback as well.

Comment: So you are sating that it should work but since my `console.log(results)` is outside the callback function, it will be executed first that is why on the first "enter clicking" the results are not updated?

Comment: I get the error `'fetched_results' is not defined` but doing: `postQuery(query)
          .then(() => getQueryResult()
            .then(
              (fetched_results)=>setResults(fetched_results), console.log(fetched_results)
            )
          )`

Comment: I think you can do the following: `function getQueryResult() {
    return axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/query')
      .then(function (response) {
        setResults(response.data);
      })
  }` and  `function handleEnter(query){
      if (query != "") {
        postQuery(query)
          .then(() => getQueryResult()
          );
      } else {
        alert("The search query cannot be empty")
      }`. You do not see the results updated because `console.log(results)` it is executed before the `.then()`

Comment: @Prova12 Don't use an arrow shorthand, and don't use comma operators. In this case, it wasn't even a comma operator, but a comma that separates the arguments of the `then` call. Instead, use `.then(fetched_results => { setResults(fetched_results); console.log(fetched_results); })`